# Strange behaviors when adding an a to a Gradient Stop in qml

Tags: qt, qml

While working with a Slider control in Qt Quick, I changed the background to have a rectangle with a gradient background. At certain points in the project, I needed to change the color of a specific gradient stop. To do so I tried to add id to the gradient stop. However, after adding an id, the height of the slider suddenly shrinks down to a very small height. I did not change any other properties of the slider. Why is that and how can i fix it? In the code below, the height of the entire slider immediately shrunk after adding"id: grad1" to the first GradientStop.

```
Slider{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        id: sliderId
        from: 1;
        to: 1000;
        value: 20;
        width: 440;
        height: 20;
        background: Rectangle{
            implicitHeight: 4
            height: implicitHeight
            gradient: Gradient{
                orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
                GradientStop{id: grad1; position: 0.0; color:"#cf3732"}
                GradientStop{position: 0.2; color:"#db8d44"}
                GradientStop{position: 0.35; color:"#e3d430"}
                GradientStop{position: 0.5; color:"#29c910"}
                GradientStop{position: 0.65; color:"#e3d430"}
                GradientStop{position: 0.8; color:"#db8d44"}
                GradientStop{position: 1.0; color:"#cf3732"}
            }
            Rectangle {
                height: parent.height
                color: "#21be2b"
                radius: 2
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug but what do you try to do with the `height` is such a strange way? You shout define or `height` or `implicitHeight` not both of them. Btw, setting `height: 4` without assigning `implicitHeight` solves the issue.

Comment: Actually, unless you explicitly want to control the background height, you should not set a height at all. It is set by the slider control unless you set it explicitly. You _should_ set `implicitHeight` though to provide a reasonable default. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#background-prop

Comment: By the way: in order to change the color, you do not need an id. Adding an id suggests you are trying to then assign to the color? A better approach would be to use use a binding on color itself: `GradientStop{position: 0; color: conditionFulfilled ? "#aaaaaa" : "#bbbbbb"}`

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! @André I removed setting the height and only set the implicit height. It works now!